# Remove completely borders of an external window

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to remove completely all borders of an external window using winapi.

Right now I have achieved the following result by using this code:

[image]

```
    public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    public static int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000; //window with border
    public static int WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000; //window with double border but no title
    public static int WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME; //window with a title bar
    private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;      //window with no borders etc.
    private const int WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;
    private const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;  //window with minimizebox

      public static void HideWindowBorders(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        int style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE); //gets current style
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, (style & ~WS_CAPTION)); //removes caption from current style
    }
```

This removes the caption and the min/max/close buttons (oddly only after resizing the window). However, this does not remove the thin border that allows resizing the window.

How can than borders be removed?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the WS_THICKFRAME window style?  If I recall that controls whether or not the window has a "resize" border.  As far as only changing after resizing, you need the non-client area of the window to be invalidated for that to happen.  Try p/invoking RedrawWindow() with the RDW_FRAME flag.

Comment: @Tim: No, you need to follow the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) and call [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) for the new frame styles to be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        public const uint WS_SIZEBOX = 0x00040000;

    public static void HideWindowBorders(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        int style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE); //gets current style
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, (uint)(style & ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_SIZEBOX))); //removes caption and the sizebox from current style
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be looking for is WS_POPUP rather than ~WS_CAPTION.

Maybe try adding this style:

```
public const uint WS_POPUP = 0x80000000;
```

Then seettiing window long like so:

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
```

Just to further explain, WS_POPUP essentially removes any sizing/resizing, min/maximizing which leaves you with just a simple window.

Comment: No, `WS_POPUP` does not do that. `WS_POPUP` **by itself** does. You are *replacing all the styles that were already there* with `WS_POPUP`. Removing `WS_CAPTION` is the right solution, but isn't the complete solution.

Comment: I have tried it, but when the window is a popup it can't be interacted. When I click the window it hides itself (much as a popup).